# Is it possible to browse the Internet through a Radio type n network with a b/g only adapter?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, adapter

My wireless network upgraded to an n-type radio and I discovered my AWUS036H wireless booster cannot browse while connected to it simply because it supports only b/g radio networks. Is there any way I can get around this? What exactly makes it incompatible and at what level? Thanks.

Comment: Is your new router sitting on the 5ghz frequency, instead of the 2.4ghz?  Are you using WEP/WPA or WPA2 for encryption?  Model of new router?  Does it connect and get an IP address, or does it simply no longer connect?

Comment: @francisswest: I have no clue to the frequency details but it's an open network, however as Bon Gart suggested, I'll contact the administrators. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Go into the administration panel of your new wireless N router, and change the settings to allow N and G.  It is currently set to N only.

If you are not the person who upgraded to a new router, or you are not the person who set up your network, contact the person who did, and inform them that they need make this change.